# MySQL - joins with SUM() on mixed colmns

Tags: mysql, join, sum

My tables structure is as follows:

```
units {id, owner_id}
contracts {id, rent, unit_id}
rents {paid, contract_id}
```

What i need, is the sum of two things: all `rents.paid` and the sum of `contracts.rent`.

My query is:

```
SELECT 
   Sum(Rent.paid)      AS Rent__summed_rents
FROM
   rents AS Rent
LEFT JOIN contracts
   ON contracts.id = Rent.id
LEFT JOIN units
   ON contracts.unit_id = units.id AND units.owner_id = 29
```

I tried to add `contracts.rent * Rent.paid AS Rent__summed_expected_rents`, but it didn't work.

---

***edit***

Each `contract` has a column `rent`, which contains the payment expected for each month.
Each `rent` record has a column `paid` which contains the actual payment made.
The query should get all the paid records and sum them (summed_rents), it also should tell me what was the expected income (which is `contracts.rent` * rents.paid)

*** edit #2 ***

```
rents data:
id | paid | contract_id
 1 | 200  |      6
 1 | 300  |      6
 1 | 500  |      4
 1 | 200  |      4

contracts data:
id | rent |  unit_id
 6 | 500  |    22
 4 | 600  |    22

units data:
id | owner_id
22 |    29
```

What i expect is: 
summed rents = 1,200 (sum of all paid)
expected rents = 2,200 = (500 * 2) + (600 *2) (sum of contract.rent, one for each `rents` record)

Comment: It isn't clear what you need. You say you need the sum of `contracts.rent` but what then is the product `contracts.rent * Rent.paid` used for?

Comment: Can you add an example with the data and the expected results?

Comment: @Serpiton data sample added, thanks

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski another edit, with data sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd build the query:

start with units for an owner. simple enough:

```
SELECT u.*
  FROM units u
 WHERE u.owner_id = 29
```

next step, get the contracts on those units:

```
SELECT c.*
     , u.*
  FROM units u
  JOIN contracts c
    ON c.unit_id = u.id
 WHERE u.owner_id = 29
```

next step, get the rents paid on those contracts

```
SELECT r.*
     , c.*
     , u.*
  FROM units u
  JOIN contracts c
    ON c.unit_id = u.id
  JOIN rents r
    ON r.contract_id = c.id
 WHERE u.owner_id = 29
```

-- aggregate the rows from that result by contracts id (per the specification, we need the count from rents by contract number, to multiply by the contracts rent amount)

```
SELECT SUM(r.paid) AS total_paid
     , SUM(c.rent) AS total_rent
  FROM units u
  JOIN contracts c
    ON c.unit_id = u.id
  JOIN rents r
    ON r.contract_id = c.id
 WHERE u.owner_id = 29
 GROUP BY c.id
```

-- get grand totals by wrapping that result as an inline view, and aggregating the total_paid and total rent

```
SELECT SUM(t.total_paid) AS total_paid
     , SUM(t.total_rent) AS total_rent
  FROM (
         SELECT SUM(r.paid) AS total_paid
              , SUM(c.rent) AS total_rent
           FROM units u
           JOIN contracts c
             ON c.unit_id = u.id
           JOIN rents r
             ON r.contract_id = c.id
          WHERE u.owner_id = 29
          GROUP BY c.id
       ) t
```

---

**NOTE:** counting the number of rows in `rents` for a given contract seems an odd way to get the multiplier for rent. But if that's the specification, we make sure our code does that.

We'd only need outer joins to generate "zero" paid and "zero" rent. If we introduce a LEFT JOIN to the rents table, then we'd need to adjust the expression to get total_rent. We'd want to use something like:

```
   c.rent*COUNT(r.contract_id) AS total_rent
```

Something like this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(t.total_paid),0) AS total_paid
     , IFNULL(SUM(t.total_rent),0) AS total_rent
  FROM (
         SELECT SUM(r.paid) AS total_paid
              , c.rent*COUNT(r.contract_id) AS total_rent
           FROM units u
           JOIN contracts c
             ON c.unit_id = u.id
           LEFT
           JOIN rents r
             ON r.contract_id = c.id
          WHERE u.owner_id = 29
          GROUP BY c.id
       ) t
```

Comment: @yossi: If the "zero" totals aren't necessary (i.e. it's okay to omit rows where no rent is yet paid on a contract), then the inline view may not be necessary, and simply removing the `GROUP BY c.id` from that inner query may return the result you specified. This query won't return rows for `units` that don't have a contract, you'd need to make the JOIN to contracts into an outer join as well, adding a LEFT keyword. The expressions in the SELECT list might need to be adjusted to handle NULL values when no matching row is returned, use the `IFNULL` function to replace NULL with zero.

Answer (score 1):

It's as easy as:

```
select sum(r.paid) as rent_paid,
       sum(c.rent) as expected_rent
  from rents r
  join contracts c on (r.contract_id = c.id)
  join units u on (c.unit_id = u.id)
 where u.owner_id = 29;
```

As seen on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/709aaf/1)